# Cannot open immediate window when debugging WPF VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, immediate-window

I can't get the Immediate Window to open using VS2010 Express Edition in WPF. I have opened countless times by setting break points and hitting ctrl-G or from the menu. I don't get any error message and I *can* open it when I am not in debug mode. The break points do work, btw.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I don't get to thank anyone for help. But I found the answer myself anyway:

**Tools -> Settings -> Import and Export Settings -> Reset all settings.**

Unlike others who have this problem, I have always had this function in the menu under Debug -> Windows -> Immediate, or Ctrl-G. I hope this helps someone.